# How to convert RECORD in Fortran to C language?

Tags: c, fortran

Does anybody know how to convert RECORD in Fortran to C language?

for example in Fortran:

RECORD /ABC/ MY_RECORD

Thanks,

Comment: Woooosh.... that took me back 20 or 30 years.

Answer (score 2):

A FORTRAN structure is pretty much like a C structure, right?

> struct ABC MY_RECORD;

Should be fine, assuming you've converted the `STRUCTURE /ABC/` definition already.